Julia: PCRE.exec error: match limit exceeded when using Regex
I'm trying to apply a rather complex regex to a large string in Julia. For reproducibility, the string is:
A = "6666666666666666666666666666611111122222221222222222222222222233361222222222233232336611116111112212211666666666666666666666666666666666111111111121122221222122122222222222222222222222222112222122222222222222222222222222333333332112661222122222222222222222222222222222222222222222222555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555522222222222222222222122222222222333261222222222222222222223333331222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222622222222222222222222222222222233333312222222222612222222222222122255555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555522222222222222222222223332122233222333333333333333333333333333333611112222211222222222222222222222222222222212222222222222212221111225555555555555555555555555555551222222222222222222212221121122212222222222222222222222222221222222222222222555555555555555155555555555155555555555555555555555555555555555555111111222222222212222222222222222222222222222222222122221222222222222222222222221212222222222222225555555555555555555555555511555555555222222222222212222222212222222222222222222222222266"

The regex in question is pattern_fl = Regex("(?:[234](1*|6*|5*)){$n,}(?:5|6{$m,}|\$)"). This regex is supposed to capture sequences of 2,3,4 that

(1) May contain 1s, 6s or 5s in between
(2) Have a length of >= n where n is a variable set to 30, but any 1s, 5s or 6s should not contribue to the count.
(3) End with a single 5 or with >=m repetitions of 6, where m=10 is a variable.

Code for reproduction:
A = "6666666666666666666666666666611111122222221222222222222222222233361222222222233232336611116111112212211666666666666666666666666666666666111111111121122221222122122222222222222222222222222112222122222222222222222222222222333333332112661222122222222222222222222222222222222222222222222555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555522222222222222222222122222222222333261222222222222222222223333331222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222622222222222222222222222222222233333312222222222612222222222222122255555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555522222222222222222222223332122233222333333333333333333333333333333611112222211222222222222222222222222222222212222222222222212221111225555555555555555555555555555551222222222222222222212221121122212222222222222222222222222221222222222222222555555555555555155555555555155555555555555555555555555555555555555111111222222222212222222222222222222222222222222222122221222222222222222222222221212222222222222225555555555555555555555555511555555555222222222222212222222212222222222222222222222222266"
n = 30
m = 10
pattern_fl = Regex("(?:[234](1*|6*|5*)){$n,}(?:5|6{$m,}|\$)")
x = eachmatch(pattern_fl, A)
for match in x
    print(match.match)
end

The expected output is to have each regex match printed. The actual output is
PCRE.exec error: match limit exceeded

Stacktrace:
 [1] error(s::String)
   @ Base ./error.jl:35
 [2] exec(re::Ptr{Nothing}, subject::String, offset::Int64, options::UInt32, match_data::Ptr{Nothing})
   @ Base.PCRE ./pcre.jl:197
 [3] exec_r_data
   @ ./pcre.jl:210 [inlined]
 [4] match(re::Regex, str::String, idx::Int64, add_opts::UInt32)
   @ Base ./regex.jl:385
 [5] iterate
   @ ./regex.jl:703 [inlined]
 [6] iterate(itr::Base.RegexMatchIterator)
   @ Base ./regex.jl:701
 [7] top-level scope
   @ ./In[458]:13

I gather that my regex expression is too flexible and its search tree produces some kind of overflow? A direct approach would be to find an equivalent, yet more concise regular expression. However, as you can see, I'm looking for a rather flexible set of matches, and I wasn't able to simplify the regex any further.
I have been struggling with producing this regex a lot. At this point I'm open to solutions in other languages, particularly Python.

Try to replace the (1*|6*|5*) in the regex with (1+|6+|5+|). I don't know Julia but Python, so I don't know if my proposed change works correctly (or at all).

That actually worked. Could you explain the purpose of the | symbol before the right-hand parenthesis?

It just means "or nothing", either (like here) only for a subexpression in parentheses or at the end of a regex for the whole regex.

@MichaelButscher, the selected answer here states that Julia uses th PCRE2 regex engine.

As @Michael_Butscher has pointed out in the comments, replacing the * with + and adding a | before the right hand-parentheses should fix it.
A = "6666666666666666666666666666611111122222221222222222222222222233361222222222233232336611116111112212211666666666666666666666666666666666111111111121122221222122122222222222222222222222222112222122222222222222222222222222333333332112661222122222222222222222222222222222222222222222222555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555522222222222222222222122222222222333261222222222222222222223333331222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222622222222222222222222222222222233333312222222222612222222222222122255555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555522222222222222222222223332122233222333333333333333333333333333333611112222211222222222222222222222222222222212222222222222212221111225555555555555555555555555555551222222222222222222212221121122212222222222222222222222222221222222222222222555555555555555155555555555155555555555555555555555555555555555555111111222222222212222222222222222222222222222222222122221222222222222222222222221212222222222222225555555555555555555555555511555555555222222222222212222222212222222222222222222222222266"
n = 30
m = 10
pattern_fl = Regex("(?:[234](1+|6+|5+|)){$n,}(?:5|6{$m,}|\$)")
x = eachmatch(pattern_fl, A)
for match in x
    println(match.match)
end

Output:
2221222222222222222222222222222222222222222222225555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555
222221122222222222222222222222222222221222222222222221222111122555555555555555555555555555555
222222222222222222212221121122212222222222222222222222222221222222222222222555555555555555
2222222222122222222222222222222222222222222221222212222222222222222222222212122222222222222255555555555555555555555555
222222222222212222222212222222222222222222222222266

Usually | represents "Either or", where the usual syntax is a|b, but just having a| will result in "or nothing".
